# Cucumber features taking time to Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have cucumber features of 12,000 lines of code for rails 2 application.
I am running all the features for getting code coverage of application code like controller, model, helpers, view pages code.
To run all the features it requires 4 hours.
Still i am not getting 100% code coverage, my question is how to get 100% code coverage via cucumber features and how to reduce the run time of all the features from 4 hours to minimum feasible time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are plenty of pages regarding speeding up Cucumber in general, e.g. http://aaron-jensen.com/post/5019042852/speed-up-your-rspec-cucumber-run is one.

You may need to look at profiling since what's making your Cucumber slow might be specific to your code and only you can see that.

Bear in mind that integration tests do have a reputation for being slow, as they're testing the full stack (and that's the point). This is why people often have thorough unit tests but not thorough integration tests, because testing everything at the integration level is just too slow.

Regarding getting better coverage, if you're using a coverage report to tell you how much is covered, it should tell you in its HTML reports which lines are not covered, and you can tailor a test for that.

However, it's actually possible there are things that you can't test in the user interface, because they're there for robustness - i.e. things you don't expect to occur in practice, but you're handling just in case they do for unanticipated reasons, or due to future code changes. In these cases, unit tests may be the only way to cover those lines of code.

Comment: Can't we get 100% code coverage using cucumber features? Actually my client wants all the lines of code appearing in rcov report as green coloured which refers to the code is covered by features and at present i am getting 70% code as red coloured i.e features are not covering that code. So, tell me is this a right way of testing code covearge?

Comment: 70% is actually a low code coverage. You'll find that the more you get, the harder it is to get the remaining points, with the last few percentage often the hardest. When I said there might be lines you can't cover in integration tests, this would probably be an exceptional case making up a percent or two.

Comment: I can't comment on why your code isn't covered, as I can't see any code or coverage reports. I'd find out which lines are not covered, figure out whether there are any tests that are supposed to cover them. Then I'd either work out how to fix the test, or add new tests to cover them.

Answer (score 0):

Of course running the feature takes time, because it actually simulate user interactions. 
You can avoid re running the same scenario by specifying the exact scenario that you want to run using

```
 cucumber path/to/file.feature:33
```

here 33 specifies line number of particular scenario in file that you want to run.

Comment: I don't want to run specific feature, as need coverage of code that gets generated in coverage.features folder in the app after running all the features at a time.